# Removed Theme still being listed in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I had a custom theme installed in `/custom/plugins`. That theme was removed recently but it is still listed when changing themes for saleschannels.

The commands `plugin:list`, `plugin:refresh` or `theme:change` do not show the removed theme.

I have checked the theme table and I was able to find it there with the active flag on 1.

Is there any way to remove it safely? There is no sales channel with that theme assigned. Should I just remove it using SQL? Is it a bug, that the removed theme is still in the theme table?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just remove it in the database. The entity doesn't have any other vital associations other than the sales channel.

As for whether this is a bug: How did you delete it initially? If it was removed via the provided functions in the administration for example, it should've left no remnants.